# Execute multiple database calls through different threads all at once

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

After successfully executing database calls in the background using `Task` to not freeze the UI, I noticed using the state of the tasks that only one database call at a time can be possible. The UI does not freeze but the results are a bit delayed if a call takes a lot of time.

For example, when these calls are executing seperately, I have **CALL 1** that takes ~7 seconds to retrieve data, and **CALL 2** is pretty instant and takes 550ms to retrieve data. But when I call **CALL 1** then **CALL 2** just after it, **CALL 2** does not retrieve data until **CALL 1** is done: **CALL 2** states indicates *RUNNING* until **CALL 1** states indicates *SUCCEEDED*.

Is there a way to make multiple calls at the same time through different threads without one blocking the other ?

Here is a sample of the code I use to make a call (**CALL 1**) to the database :

```
private void loadHistoriqueVentesData() {
   LocalDate dateDebut = MHDateDebutField.getValue();
   LocalDate dateFin = MHDateFinField.getValue();
   String searchString = MHSearchField.getText().trim();

   if (dateDebut == null || dateFin == null)
       return;

   if (!MHEspeceCheck.isSelected() && !MHDebitCheck.isSelected())
       return;
   

   loadingHbox.setVisible(true);

   Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
       @Override
       protected Void call() {
           if (!searchString.isBlank()) {
               MHHistoriqueTable.setItems(db.getProduitsVendusParPeriode(dateDebut, dateFin, MHEspeceCheck.isSelected(), MHDebitCheck.isSelected(), searchString));
               MHHNbreResultatsText.setText(MHHistoriqueTable.getItems().size() + " vente(s)");
           }
           return null;
       }
   };

   //stateProperty for Task:
   task.stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newState) -> {
       System.out.println(newState);
       if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
           loadingHbox.setVisible(false);
       }
   });
   exec.execute(task);
}


public ObservableList<ProduitVendu> getProduitsVendusParPeriode(LocalDate dateDebut, LocalDate dateFin, boolean isEspece, boolean isDebit, String nomSearch) {
   try {
       ObservableList<ProduitVendu> result = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

       String sql = "SELECT id_produit_vendu, PV.numero_bon, reference, designation, quantite, prix_vendu, benefice, date_vente, heure_vente FROM PRODUITS_VENDUS PV, HISTORIQUE_VENTES HV WHERE designation LIKE ? AND PV.numero_bon=HV.numero_bon AND HV.date_vente BETWEEN ? AND ?";
       if (isEspece && !isDebit)
           sql = sql + " AND HV.numero_bon NOT IN (SELECT AC.numero_bon FROM adherents_conso AC UNION SELECT PC.numero_bon FROM personnel_conso PC)";
       if (!isEspece && isDebit)
           sql = sql + " AND HV.numero_bon IN (SELECT AC.numero_bon FROM adherents_conso AC UNION SELECT PC.numero_bon FROM personnel_conso PC)";
       sql = sql + " ORDER BY PV.numero_bon DESC";

       PreparedStatement prepare = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
       prepare.setString(1, "%" + nomSearch + "%");
       prepare.setString(2, dateDebut.toString());
       prepare.setString(3, dateFin.toString());

       ResultSet rs = prepare.executeQuery();

       while (rs.next()) {
           int idProduitVendu = rs.getInt("id_produit_vendu");
           int numeroBon = rs.getInt("numero_bon");
           int reference = rs.getInt("reference");
           String designation = rs.getString("designation");
           int quantite = rs.getInt("quantite");
           double prixVendu = rs.getDouble("prix_vendu");
           double benefice = rs.getDouble("benefice");
           LocalDate dateVente = rs.getDate("date_vente").toLocalDate();
           LocalTime heureVente = rs.getTime("heure_vente").toLocalTime();

           result.add(new ProduitVendu(idProduitVendu, numeroBon, reference, designation, quantite, prixVendu, benefice, dateVente, heureVente));
       }
       rs.close();

       return result;
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
}
```

P.S.: `exec` is a `java.util.concurrent.Executor` and im using MySQL for database.

Comment: What implementation of `Executor` is used for `exec`?

Comment: And how are you handling connections? Are you using a single connection, or a connection pool?

Comment: (It sounds like you are already submitting these on different threads, but using the same connection. MySQL will only allocate one server-side thread per connection, so the second call will not be able to retrieve data until the first call completes. Also note that even with multiple connections, if tables are locked then even other connections can be blocked by the first connection.)

Comment: @James_D i dont know if Im understanding you correctly, but this is how I implemented `exec` :  ```exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });```

Comment: @James_D for the connection im using a single connection, there is a class called DataHandler where all the requests to the database are made, and the instance of this class is shared across all the controllers. From your last comment, I guess what I am trying to achieve is impossible since im using the same connection, and even a connection pool can't fix the issue.

Comment: *"for the connection im using a single connection"* This is the problem. *"even a connection pool can't fix the issue"*. No, this is not necessarily correct. If you use a connection pool, then each request will have its own connection, and MySQL will assign a thread for each connection. As long as the database calls don't require transactional locking (e.g. if you're only reading data), they should be able to proceed in parallel.

Comment: All you need to do is modify the `DataHandler` class so it uses a connection pool instead of a single connection. Since you have factored the database access into a separate class (which is good practice for exactly this kind of reason) it should be a fairly simple modification.

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp) on how to add the Hikari connection pool to your application, in case that might help you.  Hikari is the same connection pool that Spring uses.  But if you don't need all of the other stuff and complexity in Spring and you already have a working app based on simple JDBC connections, just adding Hikari to your app by following the linked tutorial should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: After some research and tests, I came with a solution but Im not sure if this is how it is supposed to be coded: i changed the `DataHandler` class a bit and used Hikari as suggested by @jewelsea, I removed the `Connection conn` static variable, created a datasource and used `try (Connection conn = datasource.getConnection()) {}` before *EACH* call to the database (`datasource` is a `HikariDataSource`), I got the result I wanted but i dont know if my code is now optimal.

Comment: @AbderaoufBoucenna you can [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  If you provide enough detail in the answer it will likely be reviewed and feedback provided (unless it is all OK, in which case it will just be upvoted).  If you are using Hikari correctly (sounds like you are), the solution will be pretty optimal.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

As suggested by @jewelsea in the comments, I implemented HikariCP to my DAO to use a connection pool.
This is how my DAO looked before :

```
public class DataHandler {
    private static DataHandler handler = null;
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;
    private boolean connected = false;

    private DataHandler() {
        dbConnection("localhost:3306");

        if (getConnection() == null) {
            connected = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void dbConnection(String ipPort) {
        try {
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + ipPort + "/database?serverTimezone=UTC";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "user", "password");

            connected = true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            connected = false;
        }
    }

    public static DataHandler getInstance() {
        if (handler == null) handler = new DataHandler();

        return handler;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return DataHandler.conn;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }

    // To retrieve data or to do any call to the database, the functions looked like this
    public void loadAdherents() {
        try {
            adherents.clear();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM ADHERENTS ORDER BY nom_prenom";
            ResultSet rs = getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                /* DATA FETCHING */
            }

            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I was using a ***single connection*** `Connection conn` to make any call to the database, which was highly likely the "issue" with my program.

After implementing HikariCP, my DAO became like this (pay attention to the try-catch when retrieving data) :

```
public class DataHandler {
    private static DataHandler handler = null;
    private static HikariDataSource dataSource = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;
    private boolean connected = false;

    private DataHandler() {
        dbConnection("localhost:3306");

        if (getDataSource() == null) {
            connected = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void dbConnection(String ipPort) {
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + ipPort + "/database?serverTimezone=UTC";

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

        config.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
        config.setUsername("user");
        config.setPassword("password");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("useLocalSessionState", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cacheResultSetMetadata", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("elideSetAutoCommits", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("maintainTimeStats", "false");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
        config.setAutoCommit(true);

        try {
            dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
            connected = true;
        } catch (HikariPool.PoolInitializationException e) {
            connected = false;
        }
    }

    public static DataHandler getInstance() {
        if (handler == null) handler = new DataHandler();

        return handler;
    }

    public static HikariDataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return getDataSource().getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }

    // I had to add Connection conn = getConnection() in every try-catch to get a connection
    // from the connection pool
    // and the try-catch block automatically closes the connection once its done
    public void loadAdherents() {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            adherents.clear();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM ADHERENTS ORDER BY nom_prenom";
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                /* FETCHING DATA */
            }

            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Before every call to the database, I added `try (Connection conn = getConnection())` to use a connection from the connection pool.

Answer (score -2):

By using a thread pool executor the tasks will be executed on a separate thread.

```
private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n); 
//n the number of threads

loadingHbox.setVisible(true);

   Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
       @Override
       protected Void call() {
           if (!searchString.isBlank()) {
               MHHistoriqueTable.setItems(db.getProduitsVendusParPeriode(dateDebut, dateFin, MHEspeceCheck.isSelected(), MHDebitCheck.isSelected(), searchString));
               MHHNbreResultatsText.setText(MHHistoriqueTable.getItems().size() + " vente(s)");
           }
           return null;
       }
   };

exec.submit(task);
```

Make sure to shutdown the task aswell.